# How to detect shake event with Expo React-Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, accelerometer

I would like to know if it's possible to detect shake event with Expo ?

Comment: Google got me this: https://libraries.io/npm/react-native-shake-event

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my project is on Expo. I can not add a library with native code. I would not like to leave Expo

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DeviceMotion](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/devicemotion/) and adding a event listener for `rotationRate`.

> rotationRate (object) -- Rotation rates of the device around each of its axes as an object with alpha, beta, gamma keys where alpha is around Z axis, beta for X axis and gamma for Y axis.

With this you can also look in what axis the user is rotating the phone (maybe you want different actions depending on the shake direction).